# VLookUpFunction VBA - not returning desired values

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently at my wits' end and simply cannot seem to understand why a simple vlookupfunction won't work.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

A = Textbox1.Value
B = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G20")

BaneOfMyExistence = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(A, B, 5, False)

BaneOfMyExistence = Textbox2.Value

End Sub
```

I've scoured quite some forums, and a lot of people seem to be experiecing issues with the vlookup function. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find an applicable solution.

I'd like the macro to find a match (the rownumbers are listed in the A column) with the numeric variable in textbox1, and paste the value of textbox2, also numeric, in BaneofMyExistence.

I've tried many different approaches/syntaxes which've gotten me many different errors. The current code however is not returning any error, nor is it returning any value in a designated cell.

Could someone kindly help me out?

Comment: Do you mean `Textbox2.Value = BaneOfMyExistence ` ?

Comment: Is `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")` numbers or text?

Comment: @Jeeped Column A is filled with numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left a lot of questions unanswered but I believe that you are trying to find text-that-looks like a number in a column of true numbers. Simply put, `99<>"99"`.

You've made no variable declarations so all vars have been implicitly declared as variants. A variant can be a true number or text or text-that-looks-like-a-number.

```
A = Textbox1.Value
```

This is going to put a string value into A even if there appears to be a number in the text box. Ia string will never be matched in a column of true numbers.

Set B as the range you want to lookup. You are creating a 2-D variant array with the syntax you were using.

Use application.vlookup and you can test for 'no match' with IsError.

You are overwriting BaneOfMyExistence with the value from Textbox2.Value which I assume is a zero-length string. Reversethis to put the value from the vlookup into Textbox2.

```
option explicit

Sub Button3_Click()

    dim A as long, B as range, BaneOfMyExistence as variant

    A = clng(Textbox1.Value)
    SET B = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20")

    BaneOfMyExistence = Application.match(A, B, 0)

    if not iserror(BaneOfMyExistence) then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.cells(BaneOfMyExistence, "E") = Textbox2.Value
    else
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.cells(BaneOfMyExistence, "E") = "no match"
    end if

End Sub
```

Use [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3zX8.gif) and you see a lot of your problems disappear.

Comment: I've copied this code but it simply is not returning any value. Let's say I enter 12 in textbox1, and 8 in textbox2. I'd want it to lookup column A (filled with numbers 1 to n) and in this case, paste 8 (textbox2) in cell E12. However, If I enter a value higher than the highest value in my A column I do get "no match", so that part is working.

Comment: I've also added in Option Explicit in the same manner that is depicted in the hyperlink. But within vba Option Explicit is divided by a line with the rest of the code, is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: You seem to have confused VLOOKUP (which returns a value) with MATCH (which return the matching row number). See edit above.

Comment: Oh, I was under the assumption VLOOKUP would do the trick, it works like a charm now. Thank you!